# how do i translate this C# attribute to VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am an ASP MVC 3 noobie working my way thru the music store tutorial, but translating everything into VB (I work in a VB shop).

The tutorial has a line:

```
public class Album
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string   Title      { get; set; }
}
```

How do I translate this into VB? The obvious choice is:

```
Public Class Album

    <Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")> //Compiler says:'ErrorMessage' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
    <StringLength(160)>
    Property Title As String
    Property Price As Decimal

End Class
```

But the complier is throwing an error (as shown above). It seems to think that error message is property of album.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does VB.Net have something like the C# *using* directive?  If so, are you missing one for this code?

Comment: akh2103 the fully converted method is below can you let me know if that works for you..? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be:

```
<Required(ErrorMessage := "Price is required")> _
<StringLength(160)> _
```

Check out the [VB documentation on attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711863%28v=vs.71%29) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Album
    <Required(ErrorMessage := "An Album Title is required")> _
    <StringLength(160)> _
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return m_Title
        End Get
        Set
            m_Title = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Title As String
End Class
```